# Problem Latex installation on vscode

Tags: pdftex

I try to use Latex on vscode. 
Altought, when I create a new file, there are approximately 8 others files which are created by default with .aux, .fls, .lof... I personnaly just want 3 types of files : .tex (which is created), .pdf (which is created) and also .ps (which isn't created).

I want to configure vscode so that there are only these 3 types of files created. Do you know how to fix that (I'm a beginner..)? (I use the extension called "Latex workshop" on vscode) Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: the other files are tmp files wich are needed for creating indices, glossaries, links, etc. inside the document. you can either write a script to remove them after the PDF has been typeset, delete by hand, or use the cleanup feature of vscode (if available)

Comment: the other files are needed by latex, if you delete them before the final run all cross references, tables of contents etc will not work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Only For Windows

During the development phase, we often want to build just once without having to get the cross-reference well rendered. So single invocation of `pdflatex` suffices. Invoke the batch as `SingleBuild.bat yourfilenamewithoutextension`.

```
rem let's name this batch SingleBuild.bat
echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex  "%~1.tex"

rem add other extensions you want to remove

for %%x in (aux out log toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

And for getting the cross-reference properly rendered, you need to invoke `pdflatex` twice or more. For example `MultipleBuild.bat yourinputfilenamewithoutextension 3` (for thrice invocation).

```
rem MultipleBuild.bat

echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension
rem %2 The number of invocation in draftmode

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" for /l %%x in (1,1,%2) do pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"
if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex "%~1.tex"

for %%x in (aux log out toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

**Feel free to edit my answer if you know how to invoke these two batches from Visual Studio Code. I don't have Visual Studio Code but Visual Studio 2019 Community.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and reactivity. It seems a bit complex for me, and I think, I will keep my configuration for the moment. Now, I know the importance of these files. I will try your method later when I will be more comfortable with Latex... Thanks again!